# Trailing zeroes in a Factorial

Tags: c

I am trying to write a code for calculating the number of trailing zeroes in a factorial of a specific number (large numbers). However, for small numbers, i get the correct result, but for large the deviations keeps increasing. What's wrong with my logic

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int t;

    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t > 0) {
        int factorten = 0, factorfive = 0, factortwo = 0, remainingfive = 0,
            remainingtwo = 0;
        unsigned int factors = 0;
        unsigned int n;
        scanf("%u", &n);
        for (unsigned int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
            if (i % 10 == 0) {
                factorten++;
                continue;
            } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                factorfive++;
                continue;
            } else if (i % 2 == 0) {
                // int new = i;
                // while(new % 2 == 0)
                //{
                // new = new / 2;
                factortwo++;
                //}
                continue;
            }
        }

        factors = factors + factorten;
        printf("%u\n", factors);
        if (factorfive % 2 == 0 && factorfive != 0) {
            factors = factors + (factorfive / 2);
        } else {
            remainingfive = factorfive % 2;
            factors = factors + ((factorfive - remainingfive) / 2);
        }
        printf("%u\n", factors);
        if (factortwo % 5 == 0 && factortwo != 0) {
            factors = factors + (factortwo / 5);
        } else {
            remainingtwo = factortwo % 5;
            factors = factors + ((factortwo - remainingtwo) / 5);
        }
        printf("%u\n", factors);
        if ((remainingfive * remainingtwo % 10) == 0 &&
            (remainingfive * remainingtwo % 10) != 0) {
            factors++;
        }
        printf("%u\n", factors);
        t--;
    }
}
```

Sample Input:

```
6
3
60
100
1024
23456
8735373
```

Sample Output:

```
0
14
24
253
5861
2183837
```

My OUTPUT

```
0
13
23
235
5394
2009134
```

Comment: At what size does it go wrong?

Comment: for upto 3 digits, my result is 1 less than the actual and from there it goes wrong in significant magnitude

Comment: Also, you need to count repeated factors. 4 should contribute two to factortwo, not just one. You have (commented out) code to do this, but you need similar code for 5 and 10 too.

Comment: Three digite mean you get to 100, which is 10*10 so needs to count two to factorten

Comment: The code is so bad man.

Comment: So, print out and test the correct results for factorten, factorfive etc. You can work out the correct results for small 'n' by hand.

Comment: Yes, i thought of that..When i implemented it..I get the result greater than the actual value..

Comment: @Igor In what way is it bad? I have roughly written it, but still it has very efficient time complexity if it works, there is an algorithm for this problem on the internet which provides an easy solution, but i wanted to try it on my own

Comment: @user3669055 The style of your code, can you please say what is t and what is n. And what your program needs to do. Show some input and what it should print and what it actually prints.

Comment: well it is a spoj program, so i didn't concentrate on the appearance. t is the number of test cases, n is the input number. The last print is the actual print..I used other prints for debugging purpose @Igor

Comment: "I get the result greater than the actual value." Give us some actual results (by editing your question). What do you get as factortwo, factorten etc for 10!, for instance?

Comment: Your factorfive code at the end is wrong. You don't get a zero from every two factors of 5! You get one from every factor of 5 you can pair with a factor of 2. Basically, it's all messed up. Work it out on paper first before you code it.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: ignore the first two, they are suboptimal. The third algorithm is optimal.**

I think this does what you're trying to do, but is a lot simpler and works:

```
int tzif(int n)
{
    int f2 = 0, f5 = 0;
    for (;n > 1; n--)
    {
        int x = n;
        for (;x % 2 == 0; x /= 2)
            f2++;
        for (;x % 5 == 0; x /= 5)
            f5++;
    }
    return f2 > f5 ? f5 : f2;
}
```

It counts 2-factors and 5-factors of numbers N...2. Then it returns the smaller of the two (because adding 2-factors is useless without adding 5-factors and vice-versa). Your code is too strange for me to analyze.

I think this should work too, because a factorial will have enough 2-factors to "cover" the 5-factors:

```
int tzif(int n)
{
    int f5 = 0;
    for (;n > 1; n--)
        for (x = n;x % 5 == 0; x /= 5)
            f5++;

    return f5;
}
```

This only counts 5-factors and returns that.

Another method I think should work:

```
int tzif(int n)
{
    int f5 = 0;
    for (int d = 5; d <= n; d *= 5)
        f5 += n / d;

    return f5;
}
```

Count every fifth number (each has a 5-factor), then every 25-th number (each has another 5-factor), etc.

Comment: Time limit exceeded, need a more efficient one

Comment: The problem is not svinja's code. To handle many test cases efficiently you need to reuse data between test cases.

Comment: Ok, I fixed a bug in the last one, now it should be correct and run in logarithmic time.

Answer (score 0):

Have 3 counters - c2,c5,c10.

I think the checks should be

1. divisible by 5 but not by 10 -> c5++
2. divisible by 2 but not by 10 -> c2++
3. divisible by 10. Here if true, then count number of 0's. (c10++)

At last number of 0's will be

smaller_of(c2,c5) + c10

Try to code using this. Should work.

Comment: There is no need to consider 10s, becasue they're also divisible by 5 and 2. Also, you need for any check to repeatedly divide by 2 (or 5), since (say) 25 contributes two factors of 5.

Answer (score 0):

First the `trailing 0` in `N!` are determined by factors `2 and 5` (`10`). The `factors 2` always would be more that the `factors 5` in this case you only need to calculate how `factors 5` are in the `N!`.

`(N!/5)` would give you the number of **multiple of 5 (5^1)** in `N!`
`(N!/25)` would give you the number of **multiple of 25 (5^2)** in `N!`
`(N!/125)` would give you the number of **multiple of 125 (5^3)** in `N!`
`...`
`(N!/5^n)` would give you the number of **multiple of 5^n** in `N!`

When you add the `multiple of 5` you are adding too the multiple of `25, 125, ..., 5^n`, when you add `multiple of 25` you are adding too the multiple of `125, ..., 5^n`, etc...

In that case you only need to iterate the `power of 5` less or equal than `N` and add the number of multiple of that 5 power.

Code:

```
long long trailing_zeros(long long N) {
    long long zeros = 0;
    for (long long power5 = 5; power5 <= N; power5 *= 5)
        zeros += N / power5;
    return zeros;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{

    int size,i;

    std::cin >> size;
    int*fact;
    fact = new int[size];
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> fact[size];

    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    { 

        int con = 5;
        int multiple = 0;


        do
        {
            multiple = multiple+(fact[size] / con);
            con = con * 5;

        } while (con < fact[size]);
        std::cout << multiple <<'\n';


    }
    return 0;
}
```

this code works perfectly for a single input..bt for multiple inputs it prints the o/p for the last entered number...what is wrong..i jst cant think off it