# factorial with trailing zeros, but without calculating factorial

Tags: javascript

I'm calculating the trailing zeros of a factorial. My solution is to calculate the factorial then determine how many trailing zeros it has. As you can imagine this isn't very scalable. How can I solve this without calculating the factorial?

I've found these pages on SO: 
[Trailing zeroes in a Factorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764514/trailing-zeroes-in-a-factorial)
[Calculating the factorial without trailing zeros efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33340158/calculating-the-factorial-without-trailing-zeros-efficiently)

However, neither are in Javascript. If you downvote this question please let me know why. Thank-you for your time and feedback.

My solution:

```
function zeros(n) {
  var result = [];
  var count = 0;

  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    result.push(i);
  } //generating range for factorial function

  var factorial = result.reduce(function(acc, el) {
    return acc * el;
  }, 1); //calculating factorial

  factorial = factorial.toString().split('');

  for (var j = factorial.length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
    if (parseInt(factorial[j]) === 0) {
      count += 1;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  } //counting trailing zeros

  return count;
}
```

Comment: Surely it's trivial to convert the C code into JavaScript. In fact [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25764907) you can just change the first `int` to `function` and the rest of the `int` inside the function into `var` and it runs as JavaScript.

Comment: @JJJ I don't know anything about C I didn't know they were that similar. Thankyou!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Knowing the number of trailing zeroes in a number comes down to knowing how many times it can be divided by 10, i.e. by both 5 and 2.

With factorial numbers that is quite easy to count:

```
f! = 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.10.11.12.13.14.15.16. ... .f
             ^          ^              ^
```

The places where a factor 5 gets into the final product are marked. It is clear that factors of 2 occur more often, so the count of factors of 5 are determining the number of trailing zeroes.

Now, when the factor 25 occurs, it should be counted for 2; likewise 125 should count for 3 factors of 5, etc.

You can cover for that with a loop like this:

```
function zeros(n) {
    var result = 0;
    while (n = Math.floor(n / 5)) result += n;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Very much appreciate your comment, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n=23;
    String fact= factorial(BigInteger.valueOf(23)).toString();
    System.out.format("Factorial value of %d is %s\n", n,fact);
    int len=fact.length();
    //Check end with zeros
    if(fact.matches(".*0*$")){
        String[] su=fact.split("0*$");
        //Split the pattern from whole string
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fact.split("0*$")));
       //Subtract from the total length 
        System.out.println("Count of trailing zeros "+(len-su[0].length()));
       }

  } 

     public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n) {
    if (n.equals(BigInteger.ONE) || n.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    }
    return n.multiply(factorial(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to calculate the factorial product to count the trailing zeroes.

Here a sample to count the number of trailing zeroes in n!

```
    temp = 5;
    zeroes = 0;
    //counting the sum of multiples of 5,5^2,5^3....present in n!
    while(n>=temp){
        fives = n/temp;
        zeroes = zeroes + fives;
        temp = temp*5;  
    }
    printf("%d",zeroes);
```

Note that each multiple of 5 in the factorial product will contribute 1 to the number of trailing zeros. On top of this, each multiple of 25 will contribute an additional 1 to the number of trailing zeros. Then, each multiple of 125 will contribute another 1 to the number of trailing zeros, and so on.

Here's a great link to understand the concept behind this: https://brilliant.org/wiki/trailing-number-of-zeros/

Answer (score 1):

I came across this algorithm somewhere on here can not remember now, but it looks like this,

```
def zeros(n)
    return 0 if n.zero?
    k = (Math.log(n)/Math.log(5)).to_i
    m = 5**k
    n*(m-1)/(4*m)
end
```

This very effiecient as it does not need a loop.

You can further optimize it to look like this.

```
def zeros(n)
   return 0 if n.zero?
   n*(n-1)/(4*n)
end
```

A javascript translation of this will be.

```
function zeros(n) {
   if (n == 0) return 0;
   return n * (n-1)/(4*n);
}
```

Note that this algorithm is correct till about `n >= 1000000000`, in which case the return value has an error margin of `+1`, and this error margin increases by `+1` every `n * 10000`.