# find the trailing zeroes of the factorial

Tags: javascript, data-structures

the question asks that how many zeros are their at the end of the digit,
for example if factorial of 5 is 120 then result is 1 because there is only one zero at the end if there was 2 zeros then result is 2.

so I have traied this logic in javascript to solove this problem, and for different numbers its working but for some test cases its not showing the desired output.

Can't figure out why am getting the error, if any one has a better optimized code please do share and point out the mistake that am doing

```js
const fun=(n)=>
{
   

 let fact = 1;
    let counter = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        fact *= i
    }
        while (fact % 10 == 0) {
            let val = fact / 10;
            fact = val;
            counter++
        }
    
    return counter


}
console.log(fun(5))
```

Comment: What are the test cases which fail? Big numbers that cannot be stored in javascript numbers?

Comment: 1. If you want both the factorial result and the number of trailing zeros, you could write a function which calculates the factorial of a number, but uses string instead of number. 2. If you only want the number of trailing zeros, you can store the number of zeros without calculating the factorial result. You should calculate how many times the factorial is divided by 10. In that case your question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370424/factorial-with-trailing-zeros-but-without-calculating-factorial).

Comment: Nice! Mathematics can very often work better than complicated scripts.

Comment: The number data type in JavaScript is only accurate to about 16 decimal digits, and as 18! already has that many digits, you cannot hope to get accurate results for when n is much greater.

Answer (score 1):

Your function works for all numbers as long as they don't become too big, javascript has a hard time with big numbers. One easy way to fix it is to count the zeros while doing the factors.

```
const fun=(n)=>
{
    let fact = 1;
    let counter = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      fact *= i;
      if(fact % 10 == 0){
        fact/=10;
        counter++;
      }
    }
  return counter
}
console.log(fun(24));
```

This still has a limit, but might be high enough.